# Python - assignment surprising behaviour

Tags: python, variable-assignment

So I have come across python behaviour that surprises me and I cannot understand why does it work as it works.
Could someone explain the behaviour of the code-snipped below ? (it is created only to showcase the thing that baffles me).

```
from typing import List


def check_if_one_is_in_list(list_of_ints: List[int]=None):
    if list_of_ints and 1 in list_of_ints:
        one_in_list = True
    else:
        one_in_list = False

    return one_in_list


print(check_if_one_is_in_list(list(range(0,10))))
# Output: True

print(check_if_one_is_in_list([2,3,4]))
# Output: False

print(check_if_one_is_in_list([]))
# Output: False

print(check_if_one_is_in_list())
# Output: False


def check_if_ine_is_in_list_wh00t(list_of_ints: List[int]=None):
    one_in_list = list_of_ints and 1 in list_of_ints
    return one_in_list

print(check_if_ine_is_in_list_wh00t(list(range(0,10))))
# Output: True

print(check_if_ine_is_in_list_wh00t([2,3,4]))
# Output: False

print(check_if_ine_is_in_list_wh00t())
# Output: None
#WHY?!

print(check_if_ine_is_in_list_wh00t([]))
# Output: []
#WHY?!
```

I would expect the second function to also return True/False statements, not empty array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

```
print(None and True)
# None
print([] and True)
# []

print(None and False)
# None
print([] and False)
# []
```

and that is what you assign `one_in_list` to.

what would work in your case is (explicitly cast to `bool`):

```
def check_if_ine_is_in_list_wh00t(list_of_ints):
    one_in_list = bool(list_of_ints and 1 in list_of_ints)
    return one_in_list
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
def check_if_ine_is_in_list_wh00t(list_of_ints: List[int]=None):
    one_in_list = list_of_ints and 1 in list_of_ints
    return one_in_list
```

Your default list in `None`. When you print  `check_if_ine_is_in_list_wh00t()` you are evaluating `None and False`, it returns `None`.

In the second test:

```
print(check_if_ine_is_in_list_wh00t([]))
```

The code evaluates `[] and False` and returns `[]`. You can check it in the python console.

The first function works as when the if is evaluated the output is `True` or `False`. It gets `[]` and None that are evaluated as `False` by the if.

A solution to not use the if could be:

```
def a(list_of_ints: List[int]=None):
    return list_of_ints != None and len(list_of_ints)!=0 and 1 in list_of_ints
```

Note that the order of conditions in the return is important. Probably there are better solutions.